Want to Uninstall Linux Mint and Ubuntu 24.04 on a dual Boot System
I am currently getting a message that states low disk space on filesystem root. My laptop currently has windows 11, Ubuntu 24.04 and Linux Mint.  The goal to have dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 24.04 only. The message I am getting is below.
The filesystem root has only 649.0 MB space remaining.  This is when using ubuntu 24.04. The desired result is to dual boot.  The ubuntu and Linux mint do not have any critical files on them.  Can I uninstall ubuntu, Linux and bootloader?  Resize partitions then reinstall ubuntu?  TIA
Here is a youtube vid I found.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCCRFxKU7r4

The process involves deleting partition(s) and optionally moving and resizing other partition(s). We can't tell you exactly what to do if we do not know the partition structure of your internal disks. Open Gparted and select the drive and take a screenshot of the Gparted window.  Repeat if you have multiple disks/SSDs. Add these screenshots to your question using the picture icon above the edit window.

Also indicate in your question which OS was installed last. If it is Mint, deleting the Mint partition will break grub. You will need to reinstall grub in the remaining Ubuntu installation for it to boot.

Here is a picture from Gpartd.  ubuntu was installed last.

I didn't see any edits the the question.

You don't uninstall an OS, you just remove it...   Of course there are checks you perform before doing this (ie. ensure an OS you're going to keep controls the boot process; otherwise you'll lose capability to boot into any OS if the boot-controlling OS is removed; but this will vary on details didn't provide too). Once removed; you just allocate the space to whatever surviving OS you want (best done from live media)

First, back up any necessary files in the partitions where Ubuntu and Mint are installed.
You will have to boot from a live USB of Ubuntu 24.04, delete the partitions where Ubuntu and Mint are installed, create a new partition in the new free space, and reinstall Ubuntu there.
Note that to join the partitions where Ubuntu and Mint are installed, they need to be consecutive sectors. Otherwise, you will have to move the intermediate partitions, which takes a long time.
